# MPI create MPI_Datatype from struct containing structs with structs and typedef

Tags: types, mpi

I have a quite complex program which I have to parallel with MPI. I use MPICH3 for this.

I know the way to make a new MPI_Datatype as:

```
  typedef struct{
    float x;
    float y;
    int centroid;
} point; 
typedef struct{
    int csize;//the current size
    int tsize;//the total size
    point * data;//the data carried
} ArrayList;

const int nfields=3;
MPI_Aint disps[nfields];
int blocklens[] = {1,1,1};
MPI_Datatype types[] = {MPI_FLOAT, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_INT};

disps[0] = offsetof( point, x );
disps[1] = offsetof( point, y );
disps[2] = offsetof( point, centroid );

MPI_Datatype istruct, pstruct;
MPI_Type_create_struct(nfields, blocklens, disps, types, &istruct );
MPI_Type_create_resized( istruct, 0, (char *)&(points[1]) - (char *)(&points[0]), &pstruct );
MPI_Type_commit(&pstruct);
```

But I have to do a MPI_Datatype of the following struct BigInteger:

```
struct mylimb
{
  int x;
};
typedef struct mylimb limb;
typedef enum eBoolean
{
  FALSE = 0,
  TRUE,
} boolean;

enum eSign
{
  SIGN_POSITIVE = 0,
  SIGN_NEGATIVE,
};

typedef struct BigInteger
{
  limb limbs[1000];
  int nbrLimbs;
  enum eSign sign;
} BigInteger;
```

The struct is widely used in the code so I can not simply change it to a easier way. So can anybody tell my how I can do a MPI_Datatype from the BigInteger?
My main problem is the limb which is a mylimb  how can I concat this into my MPI_Datatype

Thanks in advance!
chrigi

Answer (score 1):

an other way to rewrite `BigInteger` is

```
typedef struct BigInteger
{
  int limbs[1000];
  int nbrLimbs;
  enum eSign sign;
} BigInteger;
```

so you can use `MPI_Type_create_struct()` with `blocklens={1000,1,1}`

my main concern is the size of `enum eSign`. if you do not mix big and little endian, you can declare it as `MPI_BYTE` and `sizeof(enum eSign)`

Answer (score 0):

Derived MPI datatypes can be freely nested in order to create even more complex ones. Nothing prevents you from creating an MPI datatype that matches `struct mylimb` and then using it in the creation of the datatype that matches `struct BigInteger`:

```c
MPI_Datatype dt_limb_temp, dt_limb;
disps[0] = offsetof(limb, x);
blocklens[0] = 0;
types[0] = MPI_INT;
MPI_Type_create_struct(1, blocklens, disps, types, &dt_limb_temp);
MPI_Type_create_resized(dt_limb_temp, 0, sizeof limb, &dt_limb);
MPI_Type_free(dt_limb_temp);

MPI_Datatype dt_biginteger;
disps[0] = offsetof(BigInteger, limbs);
disps[1] = offsetof(BigInteger, nbrLimbs);
disps[2] = offsetof(BigInteger, sign);
blocklens[0] = 1000;
blocklens[1] = blocklens[2] = 1;
types[0] = dt_limbs;
types[1] = MPI_INT;
types[2] = dt_esign;
MPI_Type_create_struct(3, blocklens, disps, types, &dt_biginteger);
MPI_Type_commit(&dt_biginteger);
```

This will work even if you add other members to `struct mylib`. The tricky part is to get the datatype `dt_esign` that matches `enum eSign`. The C standard only states that `enum`s are either `char` or an (unsigned) integer type and leaves it to the implementation to select an integer of a particular size. Therefore, `sizeof enum eSign` might differ depending on the compiler, which means that fixing the type as e.g. `MPI_INT` won't work. Fortran users are lucky as one can use `MPI_Type_match_size` to obtain a matching predefined MPI integer datatype given its size in bytes. In C one has to iterate over `MPI_CHAR`, `MPI_SHORT`, `MPI_INT`, etc. and compare their size (as returned by `MPI_Type_size`) to `sizeof enum eSign`. As the values of the `enum` are non-negative, the type will most likely be unsigned, i.e. `MPI_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, `MPI_UNSIGNED`, etc. It might be tricky (impossible?) to find out whether an unsigned type is used or not. This last part is only relevant for truly portable MPI programs that should run in heterogeneous environments, where type conversion to and from some external representation could be performed by MPI. In a homogeneous environment the `enum` can be treated as an array of bytes as suggested by Gilles.